# Ceil(-0.24) prints -0 rather than just 0 in c++

Tags: c++, ceil

Why the ceil(-0.24) prints -0 rather than 0. I worked in my machine it gives this result. I also compiled on online gdb but the result remains the same. Is there any explanation?

Comment: there is a negative zero and a positive zero.... that is the explanation

Comment: IEEE-754 defines a sign associated with all numbers, including zero. It can be used in well-designed floating-point software to distinguish certain situations where accuracy has otherwise been lost. (For example, it can give a clue about whether zero was approached from a negative origin or a positive origin.) Mathematically, −0 and +0 behave the same. In casual code, you can ignore the difference.